# Thresholding picture in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I need help thresholding a picture. I need identify different types of gummies but i cannot get past the thresholding part of my project.

I have various pictures but this is one of them:

[image]

I have done this using mean_c threshold but i need better results to find the countours after.

This is the original picture:

[image]

Comment: Please always show the code you have used when asking questions. Read the help section of this forum for guides on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get better results by converting the image from RGB to HSV color space and threshold by hue (that's color value) and saturation (that's how much color is there compared to the gray value). Using saturation you might get the most of your gummies, except the transparent ones -- these are quite hard to get.

On the other hand, you may try to use edge detections, since your paper is flat and gummies really stand out. Here's the edge detection result I've got:

[image]

---

here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2

img = cv2.imread( 'Downloads/gummies.jpg' )
img = cv2.pyrDown(cv2.pyrDown( img ))
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img, cv2.CV_8U)
cv2.normalize( laplacian, img, 0, 600, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
cv2.imshow( 'frame', img )


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you send me the code you used to get this. I tried canny edge deteccion before but i could never get a result that good. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Gonçalo I will share the code later today, sorry for the delay...